# Should i dispose SPSite and SPWeb in foreach loop?

Tags: 2010

Should i dispose SpSite and SpWeb int he following code?

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
        {
            var webApplication = Parent as SPWebApplication;

            if (webApplication == null)
            {      
                throw new ArgumentException("The Miri timerjob is running on a non-existing webapplication.");
            }

            foreach (SPSite site in webApplication.Sites)
            {
                try
                {
                    var rootWeb = site.RootWeb;

                    if (rootWeb.WebTemplateId != 40000)
                    {
                        Log.VerboseFormat("The site [{0}] is no Miri template, skip Miri Timerjob.",rootWeb.Url);

                        continue;
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error("An error occured when running the Rimi Timerjob on the site collection", ex);
                    throw;
                }
            }

        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you should not because you are referencing existing objects (SPSite and SPWeb) and not creating new one.